# Marketing Cloud SMS API Calls

Tags: marketing-cloud

We've just started working with the MC REST API but seem to be running into some trouble. Keep getting:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'xxxx'is therefore not allowed access.

When trying to use:
POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/XXXXXXXXXX/send

Now, I'm guessing this is some kinda CORS related thing, but seing as MC aren't actually hosting my files (and as far as I know it can't) is there any way this is ever going to work? I ran my call through Postman and got an OK response just can't seem to get it to work on a page of it's own...

Thanks in advance!

Cheers
Ryan

Comment: If you compare postman headers to your own, what kind of differences do you find?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryan,

Can you share your header settings?  Here's an example which works using Curl.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d \
'{"mobileNumbers": ["13175551212"], "Subscribe": false,"Resubscribe": false,"Override": true,"messageText": "Test Message for Stackexhange"}' \
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/XXXXXXXXX/send?access_token=aaabbbbcccceeeddd
```

Comment: Hi David, Thanks for the above! My previous attempt had jQuery doing the POST'ing for me, so I've now re-written using CURL based on your above example and works a treat! Thanks again. Cheers Ryan